# How can I make a regular expression to extract all anchor tags or links from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I've seen other questions which will parse either all plain links, or all anchor tags from a string, but nothing that does both.

Ideally, the regular expression will be able to parse a string like this (I'm using Python):

```
>>> import re
>>> content = '
    <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> Some other text.
    And even more text! http://stackoverflow.com
    '
>>> links = re.findall('some-regular-expression', content)
>>> print links
[u'http://www.google.com', u'http://stackoverflow.com']
```

Is it possible to produce a regular expression which would not result in duplicate links being returned? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not a python person so I can't tell you exactly what to use but whenever people start looking for a regex to parse HTML the answer is don't use a regex!  Find a good module that parses the HTML for you.

Comment: Are you trying to detect all possible URLs, or just the more common ones? Regex to perfectly match all URLs is tricky business - http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: @ShawnChin Is it not much harder to validate URLs than to just match the URLs in an HTML document either they are valid or not?

Comment: @JonasElfström I was trying to get a feel of the OP's requirements. If all he's interested in are simple `http://...` urls, then the regex can be a lot simpler than if we try to eliminate all possible false positives/negatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do, it's going to be messy.  Nevertheless, a 90% solution might resemble:

```
r'<a\s[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>|\b(\w+://[^<>\'"\t\r\n\xc2\xa0]*[^<>\'"\t\r\n\xc2\xa0 .,()])'
```

Since that pattern has two groups, it will return a list of 2-tuples; to join them, you could use a list comprehension or even a map:

```
map(''.join, re.findall(pattern, content))
```

If you want the `src` attribute of the anchor instead of the link text, the pattern gets even messier:

```
r'<a\s[^>]*src=[\'"]([^"\']*)[\'"][^>]*>[^<]*</a>|\b(\w+://[^<>\'"\t\r\n\xc2\xa0]*[^<>\'"\t\r\n\xc2\xa0 .,()])'
```

Alternatively, you can just let the second half of the pattern pick up the `src` attribute, which also alleviates the need for the string join:

```
r'\b\w+://[^<>\'"\t\r\n\xc2\xa0]*[^<>\'"\t\r\n\xc2\xa0 .,()]'
```

Once you have this much in place, you can replace any found links with something that doesn't look like a link, search for `'://'`, and update the pattern to collect what it missed.  You may also have to clean up false positives, particularly garbage at the end.  (This pattern had to find links that included spaces, in plain text, so it's particularly prone to excess greediness.)

**Warning**: Do not rely on this for future user input, particularly when security is on the line.  It is best used only for manually collecting links from existing data.

Answer (score 1):

Usually [you should never parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) since HTML isn't a regular language. Here it seems you only want to get all the http-links either they are in an A element or in text. How about getting them all and then remove the duplicates?

Try something like

```
set(re.findall("(http:\/\/.*?)[\"' <]", content))
```

and see if it serves your purpose.

Comment: Interestingly, XML no longer allows to express the forbidden `a` nesting in the formal part of the document definition (while it *is* included in the SGML version of HTML).

Comment: Sorry @KerrekSB I read the question totally wrong and have changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a regex pattern that matches all valid url is [tricky](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) [business](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls).

If all you're looking for is to detect *simple http/https URLs* within an *arbitrary string*, I could offer you this solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> content = '<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> Some other text. And even more text! http://stackoverflow.com'
>>> re.findall(r"https?://[\w\-.~/?:#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+", content)
['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.google.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com']
```

That looks for strings that start with http:// or https:// followed by one or more valid chars.

To avoid duplicate entries, use `set()`:

```
>>> list(set(re.findall(r"https?://[\w\-.~/?:#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+", content)))
['http://www.google.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use regular expressions to extract things from HTML. You should use an HTML parser.

If you also want to extract things from the text of the page then you should do that separately.

Here's how you would do it with [`lxml`](http://lxml.de):

```py
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import lxml.html as lh
import re

html = """
is.gd/test<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> Some other text.
And even more text! http://stackoverflow.com

here's a url bit.ly/test


"""

tree = lh.fromstring(html)

urls = set([])

for a in tree.xpath('//a'):
    urls.add(a.text)

for text in tree.xpath('//text()'):
    for url in re.findall(r'(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))', text):
        urls.add(url[0])

print urls
```

**Result:**

```
set(['http://www.google.com', 'bit.ly/test', 'http://stackoverflow.com', 'is.gd/test'])
```

URL matchine regex from here: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Answer (score -1):

No, it will not be able to parse string like this. Regexp are capable of simple matching and you can't handle parsing a complicated grammar as html just with one or two regexps.

Comment: By "complicated grammar" you mean "not a regular grammar", hence regular expressions aren't the right tool. HTML has a context-free grammar, though.

Comment: 1. Valid html might has context-free grammar
2. Try matching attributes that has escaped quotes or any other termination symbols